# Easytether not showing in network manager, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager

I've been using easytether on ubuntu 14.04. Now that I upgraded to 16.04 and everything is correctly installed,  easytether won't show up @ the network manager. 
I did all of the terminal commands and everything looks good. Android phone says usb connection established.But nothing happens.
At the mobile stream drivers page it tells you under notes for ubuntu 16.04 to add following line to your etc /network interface/file.
"Source-directory interface.d"
www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.
Ubuntu 16.04 note
I have not done so because I don't know how. Maybe that will fix the problem. 
Does anyone have experience with this?
Thanks

Comment: Which "mobile stream drivers page"? Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

Yea got use nano or some other text editor under did to edit the file just add that line....the rest is done by machine or code...

https://s3.amazonaws.com/easytether/android_faq.html#linuxsetup

Comment: Confirmed that on Ubuntu 18.04 this works as well.
Ubuntu 16.04, Debian 8, Mint 18:
    These versions support USB hotplug almost out-of-the-box. Just add the following line to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

    `source-directory interfaces.d`